# How do I write a setup script that copies everything but my Django app to dist-packages?

Tags: python, django

I currently have a Django project with a `setup.py` that looks like this -

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as reqs:
    install_requires = []
    for line in reqs.read().split('\n'):
        if (line and not line.startswith('--')):
            install_requires.append(line)

setup(name='my_app',
      version=__import__('my_app').__version__,
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=False,
      install_requires=install_requires)
```

On every change, I'm forced to run `python setup.py install` again, as it copies my code to `dist-packages`. I understand I can probably solve this with another script or command that will run the install command each time I restart the WSGI server (gunicorn in my case), but I'm wondering if there's a nicer way of doing this - i.e. stop just my Django project from going into `dist-packages` and get gunicorn to run it from wherever it currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python setup.py develop
```

Will create a link for your package to where you are editing it, now you won't need to re-run `python setup.py install` each time you make a change.